# setting opencv video to fullscreen android

Tags: android, video, opencv, fullscreen

i am trying to set a video to fullscreen using opencv. the input is coming from the camera.
it shows on the screen in the center but not as full screen.
relevant code:

```
public class Sample3Native extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener {
private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";

private Mat                    mRgba;
private Mat                    mGrayMat;
private Mat                    mFinalMat;

private CameraBridgeViewBase   mOpenCvCameraView;


private BaseLoaderCallback     mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
                System.loadLibrary("native_sample");




                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();



            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

public Sample3Native() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial3_surface_view);

    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial4_activity_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);


}
```

i have tried using:

```
//mOpenCvCameraView.setScaleX(0.8f);
                   // mOpenCvCameraView.setScaleY(0.4f);

                //mOpenCvCameraView.setMinimumHeight(800);
               // mOpenCvCameraView.setMinimumWidth(1000);
```

but it doesnot work.

how can i strech the frames to fill all of the screen?

Answer (score 4):

You can get a list of the available resolutions or setup manually.

If you want to get the list of the available sizes and get the optimal camera size.

```
   if (mOpenCvCameraView != null) {
        List<Size> sizes = mOpenCvCameraView.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        int mFrameWidth = width;
        int mFrameHeight = height;

        // selecting optimal camera size
        {

            double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - height) < minDiff) {
                    mFrameWidth = (int) size.width;
                    mFrameHeight = (int) size.height;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - height);
                }
            }
        }

        mOpenCvCameraView.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, mFrameWidth);
        mOpenCvCameraView.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, mFrameHeight);
    }
```

If  the optimal camera size is not fullscreen, it is easy to get the great size that the camera support from the list.

Other option is to set manually the size:

```
        mOpenCvCameraView.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1000);
        mOpenCvCameraView.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 800);
```

The source of the code is from Face Detection OpenCV version 2.4.2.

Comment: looks possible exept mOpenCvCameraView.set gives the warning "The method set(int, int) is undefined for the type CameraBridgeViewBase" , so there is no set fuction for the CameraBridgeViewBase object..

Comment: Ok, it seems that the sample changed in OpenCV 2.4.3, that use the CameraBridgeViewBase. I don't not know how the object works, but in the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.html) maybe the connectCamera(width,height) do the work. But I'm not sure, try to see if it works.

Comment: Other option is to declare the mOpenCvCameraView as a VideoCapture object, instead of CameraBridgeViewBase.

Comment: the problem with connectCamera() is that it is not visible "The method connectCamera(int, int) from the type CameraBridgeViewBase is not visible" do i need to define CameraBridgeViewBase in another way?

Comment: Try to use VideoCapture object instead of CameraBridgeViewBase. The VideoCapture have the set function.

Comment: The problem with videocapture is setting it up, its different from CameraBridgeViewBase, i tried using the tutorial but it didn't work...

Comment: From what I see on OpenCV Answers, it is a bug. I'm sorry that it not helped :( I hope that they fix the issue soon.

Comment: thanks for the effort. i will have to try and set it using CameraBridgeViewBase.

Answer (score 2):

For those who google here and just want to change the resolution,

`mOpenCvCameraView.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1000)` method is not working.

Try to use `mOpenCvCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(640, 480);`

It works for **OCV4Android2.4.5, tutorial 2, mixed processing.**

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for this, I have solved the issue (sort-of).  I cannot seem to get this to work for OpenCV v 2.4.3.  I have tried everything on the internet.  However, in OpenCV 2.4.3.2 they have added a way to set the camera size

```
disconnectCamera();
mMaxHeight = //your desired height
mMaxWidth = //your desired width
connectCamera(mMaxWidth, mMaxHeight);
```

Check out the OpenCV Tutorial 5, specifically the SampleJavaCameraView -> setResolution Method

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but you can go to the `AndroidManifest.xml` and set `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

With this you won't need to rotate de camera 90º, but your application will always be in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Natural camera orientation of the OpenCV camera is landscape so make your activity is like

> `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

and apply this theme in the Activity

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        ...
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

this trick gives you a fullscreen camera.

Answer (score -2):

Try this replace

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

code in the onCreate with

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: does not work, i have asked this also in the opencv forum: http://answers.opencv.org/question/4170/getting-video-to-play-fullscreen-android/.  the problem now is that "set" is undefined for the  CameraBridgeViewBase. maybe someone knows how to fix this