# OpenCV application - Android Camera crashes after 10 seconds

Tags: java, android, opencv, camera, crash

**Background**

In this application, I was able to launch my camera preview that was developed in Android Studio with an aim to incorporate OpenCV into it. However, I face an error; the camera preview only lasts around 10 seconds until it crashes and the app shuts down. Would there be any way to resolve this? Here is my code;

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.cv;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2
{
    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    JavaCameraView javaCameraView;
    Mat mRGBA, mRGBAT;

    private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;


    BaseLoaderCallback baseLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(MainActivity.this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status)
        {
            if (status == BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS) {
                javaCameraView.enableView();
            } else {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
        }
    };

    static
    {
        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV is Configured or Connected successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV not Working or Loaded.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.my_camera_view);


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)  {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permissions granted");
            javaCameraView.setCameraPermissionGranted();
            javaCameraView.setCameraIndex(CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_BACK);
            javaCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
            javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission prompt");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height)
    {
        mRGBA = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped()
    {
        mRGBA.release();
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
    {
        mRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();
        mRGBAT = mRGBA.t();
        Core.flip(mRGBA.t(), mRGBAT, 1);
        Imgproc.resize(mRGBAT, mRGBAT, mRGBA.size());
        return mRGBAT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (javaCameraView != null)
        {
            javaCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (javaCameraView != null)
        {
            javaCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV is Configured or Connected successfully.");
            baseLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV not Working or Loaded.");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, baseLoaderCallback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            // camera can be turned on
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            javaCameraView.setCameraPermissionGranted();
            javaCameraView.setCameraIndex(CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_FRONT);
            javaCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
            javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        } else {
            //camera will stay off
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cv">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:id="@+id/my_camera_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some further investigation on your issue and here are a few considerations:

1 - I had already suggested you in the comments of [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64423056/4092588) to release the matrices inside `onCameraFrame()` as soon as they are not needed anymore. Forgetting this can generate garbage collection issues, as outlined [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39922008/4092588) or [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/77482/android-memory-leak-on-camera-rotation/?sort=latest). You can explicitly invoke this process to happen by using the `Mat.release()` method, as the user does in the same answer. Did you try it? from my tests it was extending the 10 seconds of camera life, despite not yet fixing the bug
2 - from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39918063/4092588) instead, we can understand that transposing too many times may create other troubles. Let's give a look at your code:

```
mRGBAT = mRGBA.t();
Core.flip(mRGBA.t(), mRGBAT, 1);
```

This definitely looks like something we can improve. You are first assigning `mRGBA.t()` to `mRGBAT` but then you ask again to calculate the transpose matrix for `mRGBA` when calling `Core.flip()`. The result is already stored in `mRGBAT`, thus there is no need to perform such operation again. Then you can fix this issue like this:

```
mRGBAT = mRGBA.t();
Core.flip(mRGBAT, mRGBAT, 1);
```

3 - [there is no real difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43311610/4092588) between `Mat.t()` and `Core.transpose()` but the first is a wrapper around the second and we can directly use the latter

The entire snippet that will solve your issue is the following:

```
Mat mRGBA, mRGBAT, dst;

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height)
{
    mRGBAT = new Mat();
    dst = new Mat();
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
{
    mRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();
    Core.transpose(mRGBA, mRGBAT);
    Core.flip(mRGBAT, mRGBAT, 1);
    Imgproc.resize(mRGBAT, dst, mRGBA.size());
    mRGBA.release();
    mRGBAT.release();
    return dst;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much @Antonino! I did see your previous suggestion. However, after several tries, I had found my implementations had resulted in errors. Most likely due to my inexperience and my unawareness on how to alter the code to fit my situation. However, you have explained it brilliantly, my friend. I highly appreciate your help!

Comment: also, @Antonino, how would I be able to make the camera preview full screen, as opposed to the 1:1 box format?

Comment: @RunMildew you are starting a career in software development and my warm suggestion when you have an issue is to look around. You can find already good ideas to start with, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835077/opencv-android-camera-not-fullscreen), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376420/setting-opencv-video-to-fullscreen-android) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438897/opencv-fullscreen-using-camerabridgeviewbase-android) too. Be ready to adapt what's already out there and produce what's instead yet missing. Good luck

Comment: much appreciated! I would upvote you 1000 times if I could.

Comment: after much tedious research and countless hours spent searching, I once again return back to your recommendations to understand how I would be able to complete the final step in making a camera preview full screen. In more depth, here is [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64577351/14149296). I would greatly appreciate your expertise.

Comment: this solution solves my problem too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39952025/12305715 . I just do a mix of both